# jquery mobile autocomplete loading icon

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete

Is it possible to show a loading icon on extreme right side inside the filter input before the "X" clear text icon when we are making a remote call in jquery mobile 1.3 autocomplete.

Comment: [Please don’t use signatures in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: No Reply's in 2 days.. Is the question not clear or is it that nobody requires such thing or it isnt possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The **simplest** approach would be to substitute `delete` icon of jQM search widget before making remote call and then return it back after you finished processing. *And that IMHO makes even more sense, from the user experience, than adding a second icon.*

**First** define class for our ajax icon

```css
.ui-icon-ajax {
    background-image: url(http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/images/ajax-loader.gif);
    background-size: 18px 18px;
}
```

**Second** before we make ajax call replace icons

```js
$("form.ui-listview-filter a span.ui-btn-inner span.ui-icon")
    .removeClass("ui-icon-delete")
    .addClass("ui-icon-ajax");
```

**Third** return delete icon back

```js
$("form.ui-listview-filter a span.ui-btn-inner span.ui-icon")
    .removeClass("ui-icon-ajax")
    .addClass("ui-icon-delete");
```

**Here is working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/dcRJe/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is what jQM gives by default, i am using this for now. but i was interested in showing loading for the control specifically and not for all of the page. Basically i am looking for something like this: http://safeery2k.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/show-loading-indicator-to-autocomplete-extender/

Comment: Wow! this is nice. I initially thought it should be next to delete button but this looks better to me personally! Thanks alot @peterm !

Comment: Hi @peterm. How would you approach this for a standard input with jquery-ui autocomplete. The form.ui-listview-filter no longer applies...

Comment: @user714852 Hi. If you build a relevant jsFiddle for that scenario I can take a look.